# Do Excel/VBA arrays work differently on Windows and Mac computers?

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, mac, vba

I wrote a macro for a workmate recently copies the data from an Excel spreadsheet into a 2D array approximately 75000x58 in size, then runs through each row and extracts relevant data.

The macro works well on my Windows computer and completes in under 2 seconds.

The macro also works on my workmates Mac but takes much longer; between 2000 to 4000 seconds.

I've tried the macro on other Windows computers with lower specs than hers and the macro completes in a few seconds.

Is there a reason the Mac takes over 1000x longer?

Here is the main part of the Macro, mechArray and activityArray are only small arrays - with 4 and 10 elements each, outArray is around 120x10x2.

```
'Transfer Data
For i = 1 To UBound(inArray)
    If inArray(i, 1) >= d1 And inArray(i, 1) <= d2 _
        And UCase(inArray(i, 17)) = site Then

        x = DateDiff("d", d1, inArray(i, 1)) + 1

        y = isIn(mechArray, inArray(i, 48))
        z = isIn(activityArray, inArray(i, 49))

        If y > -1 And z > -1 Then
            outArray(x, z, 1) = outArray(x, z, 1) + inArray(i, 5)
            outArray(x, z, 2) = outArray(x, z, 2) & inArray(i, 8) & "|"   
        End If
    End If
Next i
Erase inArray
```

And this is the function 'isIn',

```
Function isIn(arr As Variant, val As Variant) As Single
    Dim i

    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If arr(i) = val Then
            isIn = i
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    isIn = -1
End Function
```

Comment: Can you share the essential parts of the macro?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to be asking this question when you only tested this on one single MAC. Try testing it on at least a few other MACs before you start getting anywhere near that conclusion. And i'm sure if you asked this on a MAC forum then somebody would say they run it and it takes two seconds.

Comment: Updated it now, Joffan

Comment: I was hoping for someone with knowledge on both MAC and Windows versions of Excel. Are there no MAC users on here? My colleague is the only MAC user in our office, the rest are all windows so I cant test it on multiple devices. 

If the answer to my question was yes, MACs or the MAC version of Excel handles data differently then I would look into changing my macro and would know for any I write in the future. 

If the answer is no, the process should still complete in 2 seconds then I can tell her she needs to take her laptop for a check up.